# How can I design Address table with different types?

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I have a Address table and different address types like Personal and Corporate. I design a table but I think is breaking normalization rules. How can I improve this design?

My design:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design appears to be pretty good overall, but I would make the following recommendations:

- You already store the client's First Name and Last Name in the `clients` table, so you can probably remove the `client_address_personal_info` table altogether. This will reduce redundant data and lead to increased performance and easier management and reporting.
- You can probably normalize the name of the `client_address_corporate_info` table to something similar as your `clients` table, e.g. `corporations`
- Similarly to the first point, you should either remove the `phone_number` field from the `clients` table or the `client_addresses` table so it's only stored in one place. (Your choice which table you want to keep it in, I've seen it done both ways.)
- One other general recommendation (though this is tangentially related to normalization) is you should size your varchar fields to something that is capable of fitting all potential future values. While obviously we can't predict the future, my point is generally leave enough space for larger values that are logically possible. VARCHAR(1) vs VARCHAR(1000) isn't going to affect performance or disk space is any measurably different way. So while most First Names or Business Names can fit inside a VARCHAR(16) field, I'm sure there's names out there that are 25+ characters long. My general starting point on something like that is VARCHAR(50) (and only in rare cases do I use a smaller sized VARCHAR).

Comment: Actually, the part I am unsure about is the address type relation. I have 2 address type: Personal and Corporate. If address_type_id equal Personal address type id, I join client_address_personal_info table. If address_type_id equal Corporate address type id, I join client_address_corporate_info table. Is this a good method?

Comment: Ah that clarifies  your question more (I wasn't exactly sure address_type was used for). I would still stand by my first point though that you should store first_name and last_name in one place, so should either remove it from the clients table or remove the client_address_personal_info table altogether and use the clients table in place. To answer your actual question, using the address_type to determine something like that is an OK implementation but it may lead to funkier or potentially inefficient SQL queries when trying to join one _info table over the other (e.g. by a case statement).

Comment: If you wanted to use that kind of design, then you're probably better off storing the address_type_id in both _info tables then so that your relationship between them and the client_addresses table is on id and address_type_id.

Comment: I can't do this because I have some reasons. For example I have client. Client Name: John. But John can create address with different name like Adam. My question is: Is good my address type relation method?

Comment: Gotcha, see my previously reply on how it might be slightly better to implement that type of relation then. (I understand your situation better now too, and you might want to consider naming your _info tables something a little more clear such that the first_name and last_name fields are not duplicate of the same fields in the clients table.)